# Re-Use object added to EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object

I am using EF 4. I want to add a row to a (message) table, so I declare a new object (newMSG), and populate it. Then I use the message table's method .AddObject(newMSG) to add the new row.

Is the newMSG object now available to "re-use" to add another row? Or do I need to have a new object? Seems like I should be able to re-use the newMSG object, but it's not so easy to test.

You guys'll know right off the bat... Of course, this would apply to any object, I assume. There's nothing special about EF....

Does it matter perhaps if I use the savechanges() method between uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new object. There is metadata attached to that newMSG object that ties it to that particular row.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess it's not too big a deal. I learned something.

Comment: Justin, one more question. If I declare the new object, then add it to the entity object, then the new object goes out of scope before I save changes to the entity, will that be an issue?

Comment: Since you have added it to the entity object, the context should still have a reference to that object. In that case, the object hasn't gone out of scope. Now if the entity object/context was to go out of scope before saving, then that would be a problem.